# Software Transactional Memory + Spring

Tags: spring, object, transactions, stm

Is it possible to integrate Spring with Software Transactional Memory so that I can rollback all Objects and DB transactions together on method throwing Exception. I need possibilities of Spring+Deuce STM or Spring+Multiverse STM. My ultimate goal is to rollback the Object States and DB state on a method throwing Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now Multiverse doesn't support this kind of integration directly but this is an interesting feature.. I am part of Multiverse team & will talk with the author to see if there is anything which will allow us to do this or prioritize this in feature set we are working on..

Thinking long................................................

A round about way of doing this is to register a PostEvent listener on a Transaction in STM and roll back the DB transaction if the STM transaction fails.. Probably this may help :)

P.S. Which version of Multiverse stm are you trying to use?

--Sai

Comment: Actually am very new to STM/Multiverse. I want the solution oriented to Spring such that Spring DB Transaction rollback restores/reverts all the Objects modified in that particular method. This is because I have a full-pledged application developed on Spring framework and I would not change my application code(other than introducing some annotations). I preferred to go with Multiverse 0.5.

Comment: You can use spring transaction event listener to see if the transaction has committed or rolledback and proceed with multiverse accordingly. I haven't tried this yet but I suppose it should work. The problem would be DB transactions are much much longer than STM transactions and we don't prefer transactions waiting so long..

Comment: In Spring the Transaction owner will be the methods. Transaction rollbacks by methods can be determined based on the exception thrown.Similarly I thought to annotate that particular method as transactional(provided by multiverse stm) so that the object state changes will be reverted. But when I provided the javaagent as VM argument in eclipse and run the application I got the Exception as  ::

Comment: Jan 28, 2011 6:06:53 PM org.multiverse.javaagent.MultiverseClassFileTransformer handleThrowable
SEVERE: Failed while instrumenting class 'com/xyz/myApp/dao/BaseDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17d35e18'. It is not possible to abort the Javaagent instrumentation process, so the JVM is going to continue, but since this class is not instrumented, it is not transactional so all bets are off.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException
 at org.multiverse.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: Can  you try without instrumentation using the TransactionalTemplates to see if this works?

Comment: Ya,I have done through Spring Declarative TX Mgt, where TX demarcations are defined in configuration files itself(ie; alternative to the programmatic approach of using TX template). But in vain. In my application in Service layer I defined a List Object with 2 entities and in DAO method where TX starts I updated the list object with 2 more entries. On the Transaction rollback I expected to the DB entry as well as List Object state to be rollback.But in vain, only DB Tx rolled back.

Comment: That is odd.. There isn't a difference b.w instrumentation & txtemplate in terms of how they work. I am not the guy who works on instrumentation so I can ask author to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yep.. Finally thats success.. I could achieve it.. Thanks alot for helping.. I have been struggling over it since a week... thank you.. And finally can u say me in short difference between using Instrumentation and using TXTemplate..

Comment: And however as I said, I would not go for modifying my code for introducing Transactions into my application this(usage of STM TX Template) will be a temporary solution. Introducing the Object transactions using annotation is preferable. So Pls do post me for the effective usage of STM Annotations in SpringFramework

Comment: I do dynamic lang integration & take care of transactional collections so I am intimate with templates more but did you use multiverse compiler to enable instrumentation or used multiverse agent?

Comment: I used multiverse agent. And the multiverse forced me to use transactional Objects only like TransactionalArrayList to rollback object states. Isn't it possible to rollback traditional objects ie; to use ArrayList,HashMap inside transactions.?

Comment: Nope.. ArrayList and HashMaps are not build with Transactional Primitives. So it isn't possible to do things like read tracking & collision detection on them. That is why we provide our own collections which confirm with java.util.collections interface

Comment: In the article "http://pveentjer.wordpress.com/2010/03/" author have talked about configuration in Spring(used DurableTransactionalObjectFactoryBean). I could not get his intention. Does he talks about using Multiverse in Spring?? I haven't find the class he specified in Spring API.

Comment: No idea what the man wrote on Spring.. I am into STMs from a different angle and I don't work with things like Spring a lot. You should probably ping that man in the post with the comment :)